# How to promote an existing index to primary key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key

I know how to make a primary key within a table, but how do I make an existing index a primary key?  I'm trying to copy an existing table from one database to another. When I show the table, the index at the bottom is in this form:

```
"my_index" PRIMARY KEY, btree (column1, column2)
```

I have created the index with:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (column1, column2)
```

But I do not know how to make it the primary key ...

UPDATE:  The version of my server is 8.3.3

Comment: If my_index is shown as the name of the primary key then you already **have** an index. There is no PK without an (unique) index in Postgres

Comment: what is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: I'm running 8.3.3

Answer (score 34):

You'd use ALTER TABLE to add the primary key *constraint*. In Postgres you can "promote" an index using the "[`ALTER TABLE .. ADD table_constraint_using_index`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)" form

Note, the index need to be unique of course for a primary key

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_my_table PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX my_index;
```

Comment: That did not work for me.  What is PK_my_table?  I assume this is a label and I append 'PK_' to the name of my table?  I got a syntax error saying "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING" at character 83"

Comment: @ngramsky:  `USING INDEX` is available since 9.1. So I guess you are not running the current version

Comment: No, I am using 8.3.3  How would I go about doing that in 8.3.3?

Comment: The only way to do it in that ancient version is to drop the index and add a new pk constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you should make that an answer: your comment predates the other answer...

Comment: If you currently don't have a *unique* index, I recommend this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188541/121426

Comment: Heads up, this solution is viable for a unique index, but not for a unique constraint, since you can't add the primary key constraint while the unique constraint exists, and you can't drop the unique constraint without also dropping the index it manages.

Also-- see Thomas B's answer below for more details on the same idea as this answer.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think its possible to convert an index into a primary key in that version of postgresql.

I would just drop the existing index and create the primary key using the columns you specified.:

```
DROP INDEX my_index;
ALTER TABLE ONLY my_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY(column1,column2);
```

Worked in 7.4 and 8.4

Comment: btw, "If ONLY is specified before the table name, only that table is altered. If ONLY is not specified, the table and all its descendant tables (if any) are altered."

Answer (score 3):

Using `PostgreSQL9.5+`, you can benefit from the unique index existence, as here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (c1 integer, c2 varchar(20));
​
CREATE TABLE
Time: 8.268 ms
​
INSERT INTO foo (c1, c2)
>  SELECT i, md5(random()::text)::varchar(20)
>  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;
​
INSERT 0 1000000
Time: 1609.967 ms (00:01.610)
​
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_idx01 ON foo(c1);
​
CREATE INDEX
Time: 305.905 ms
​
ALTER TABLE foo add constraint foo_pk primary key using index foo_idx01 ;
​
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD CONSTRAINT USING INDEX will rename index "foo_idx01" to "foo_pk"
ALTER TABLE
Time: 79.664 ms
```

> The `alter table` statement is quicker than the `create unique index` itself